# How to add an image as a single key frame

Tags: image, keyframes, 2d

I am working on a 2d animation in which i had to import images from photoshop in order to create moving bg. I am importing image as planes, but it's applied to entire timeline. I want it to be applied to a single key frame. What should I do?

Comment: you can animate the image visibility in the Outliner, put your cursor on the camera icon and press i to create a keyframe, then next frame click on the camera icon and press i again

Comment: If you don't need to animate in 3d scene, you can animate 2D in blender's Video Editor too.

Comment: If you have a sequence of images you want to display in order, one image per frame in the animation, you can convert your sequence into a movie format "Images as planes" supports, such as mp3; enable "Images as Planes" in preferences; and import the movie using "Images as Planes".  If you edit the material for the plane you can set playback options.  If you don't have other tools to make a movie, you can use the VSE as @vklidu suggests to create the movie from an image sequence.

Comment: Having similar problem..do you found the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a kind of similar problem (2d Animation, grease pencil). In my case, drawing each frame made the last frame of the animation I planned (for example: 45 frames planned, one layer) repeat till the last frame of the playback (for example 100 according to the bottom bar where it says "start" and "end"). What I did was delete with the eraser tool the drawing in the frame that started the repetition (following the same example: frame 46) that I didnt want. Then, no more repetition in the timeline or through all the playback.

I dont know if it exist a more simple way to do it, TVPaint and Adobe Animate have more intuitive option to hold a frame to a certain position  of the playback